# How to specify "http request header" in OpenURI

Tags: ruby, open-uri

I am trying to call a URL using Ruby's OpenURI gem, however it needs me to pass certain values inside its HTTP request header.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: this really helps with 422 error which is caused by Accept parameter expecting to know format like xml

Answer (score 63, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/classes/OpenURI.html), you can pass a hash of http headers as the second argument to `open`:

```
open("http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/",
   "User-Agent" => "Ruby/#{RUBY_VERSION}",
   "From" => "foo@bar.invalid",
   "Referer" => "http://www.ruby-lang.org/") {|f|
   # ...
 }
```

Comment: Use `URI.open` to avoid deprecations warnings from ruby related to confusion with `kernel#open.`

Comment: also you can pass headers as a hash, not only double splatted.