# how do I include a header in an http request in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, httprequest, net-http

Have the below code working:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/datasets/")
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
```

Now I also need to pass a header with this token hash in it:

```
token: "fjhKJFSDHKJHjfgsdfdsljh"
```

I cannot find any documentation on how to do this.  How do I do it?

Comment: There are many gems for Ruby that will make it much easier to use HTTP than Net::HTTP. I'd recommend researching those and picking one. Net::HTTP is really for those times when nothing else already exists.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478841/how-to-specify-http-request-header-in-openuri

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get_response` is a shorthand for making a request, when you need more control - do a full request yourself.

There's an example in ruby standard library [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-Setting+Headers):

```
uri = URI.parse("http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/datasets/")
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
req['token'] = 'fjhKJFSDHKJHjfgsdfdsljh'

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't that send the request twice?  When you call Net::Http.new, doesn't that send a request?

Comment: @JPB no, it initialises the request, connects to server and then sends the request.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. Probably a `https`  (SSL) issue.

Answer (score 2):

Though you surely could use `Net::HTTP` for this goal, gem [excon](https://github.com/excon/excon) allows you to do it far easier:

```
require 'excon'
url = 'http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/datasets/'
Excon.get(url, headers: {token: 'fjhKJFSDHKJHjfgsdfdsljh'})
```

Comment: That's just one of many gems which do this. [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty), [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) and [curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb) are also very popular.