# How store an image from URL with Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-uploading, imageurl, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

My question is about: How can i upload an image from URL when i'm using Active Storage. I used the code from other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51027995/how-to-save-an-image-from-a-url-with-rails-active-storage) here in Stackoverflow but passing through the model method, the param which i need to store in my table. The curiously situation is that i'm receiving the next error:

`ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature in PostsController#update`

But when i reload the show view, from this model, the images appears stored and deployed on my posts view.

Here my code in **Post model**:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  require 'open-uri'

  has_one_attached :image_one
  has_one_attached :image_two
  has_one_attached :url_image

  before_save :grab_image

  
  def grab_image(url)
    downloaded_image = open(url)
    self.url_image.attach(io: downloaded_image, filename: "map.jpg", content_type:"image/jpg")
  end
  
end
```

This is my code in the Edit Action of my **Controller**:

```
  def update
    @posturl = params[:post][:url_image]
    @post.grab_image(@posturl)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update!(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

[image: Apparently, the record is saved but i receive this problem]

I got the following links which talks about the chance to upload images from URLs but, i don´t know what else can i do:

[Active Storage Overview - EdgeGuides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#attaching-file-io-objects)

[@omnilord/rails-5-2-activestorage-mitigating-adoption-pitfalls](https://medium.com/@omnilord/rails-5-2-activestorage-mitigating-adoption-pitfalls-15a7cd769408)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this work for u:

```
file = open(url)
user.image.attach(io: file, filename: "temp.#{file.content_type_parse.first.split("/").last}", content_type: file.content_type_parse.first)
```

Comment: I will test it inside my code and will share if it works. Thanks.

Comment: I found a way to convert image files to Base64. Check this link: https://www.webres-studio.com/es/blog/como-cargar-archivos-blob-y-base64-con-active-storage-y-ajax

Comment: This code doesn't work and has no difference from the page question

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this without having to enter filename explicitly is:

```
require 'open-uri'

url = URI.parse("https://your-url.com/abc.mp3")
filename = File.basename(url.path)
file = URI.open
user = User.first
user.avatar.attach(io: file, filename: filename)
```

This automatically saves the avatar against that particular user object.

In case you are using a remote service like S3 the URL can be retrieved by:

```
user.avatar.service_url
```

Comment: service_url works for me in production, but throws an error in development I added a callback in the objects controller before_action :set_host_for_local_storage  and then private ActiveStorage::Current.host = request.base_url if Rails.application.config.active_storage.service == :local and now service_url works in both dev and production

Comment: service_url would work only when you are using an S3 like service for storing your images. You must be using your local disk for storing the assets in your development environment. Though, I liked your workaround of adding before_action to handle the same :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
file_url = image[:image_url]
download = open(file_url)
IO.copy_stream(download,
user.image.attach(
  io: download,
  filename: image[:name],
  content_type: image[:content_type],
))
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me at all. I don't know if you use this code working with Active Storage?... Please, let me know your configuration if its possible.

Comment: Normal Rails 5.2 application with Ruby 2.5.1
I even have no need to require open-uri in my model

Comment: i tried to remove the open-uri because I read that since Rails 5 it was integrated but, even that, my code doesn’t work.

Comment: This is the error I’m getting... `ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature in PostsController#update` but the most weird situation is if refresh the page, the image is stored inside the uploads folder.

Comment: Seems you placed upload method in controller.
That's not right, try to use your model for that.

Comment: Nope, I used the structure that I put in the main question. Using controller and method model to handle this task.

Answer (score 0):

While editing, you need to provide the signed id of the attached blob in case the user did not make any changes to the image.

Something like the below should work. You need to make this change in your form.

```
<%= form.file_field :image_one, value: image_one.blog.signed_id %>
```