# How to attach image from the url in Rails Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary, rails-activestorage

I want to attach an image to a record in the rake task. The only thing I have for image is the URL. This is the URL for the image https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/google-analytics-7-722699.png.

I used this approach from a StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51028368/9374364).

```rb
require 'open-uri'
downloaded_file = open(tool.image)
new_tool.image.attach(io: downloaded_file, filename: "foo.png")
```

This gives the following error.

```
ActiveStorage::IntegrityError: Unsupported source URL: #<StringIO:0x00007f9bd9759f28>
Caused by:
CloudinaryException: Unsupported source URL: #<StringIO:0x00007f9bd9759f28>
```

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I think that you should pass a string containing the image's URL to `open`:

```
require 'open-uri'

image_url = "https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/google-analytics-7-722699.png"    
downloaded_file = open(image_url)

new_tool.image.attach(io: downloaded_file, filename: "foo.png")
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. In my question, tool.image is a URL of an image.

Comment: @SalmanHaseebSheikh What are the versions of Ruby and Rails that you are using?

Comment: Ruby 2.7.0 and Rails 6.0.2.

Comment: Are you sure that `tool.image` returns a String? Can you put here the output for `tool.image.class`?

Comment: Latest versions of ruby suggest using `URI.open` instead: warning: calling URI.open via Kernel#open is deprecated, call URI.open directly or use URI#open