# How to download a picture in Rails and attach to model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model with `has_one_attached :picture`.

I implemented a method which should download the picture for the object

```
  def load_picture
    RestClient.get(url, :accept => 'image/jpg')
  end
```

(**url** attribute is working, i.e. tested by opening in a browser, it is downloading the picture)

Trying RestClient Gem here but any other solution would work too.

After the download I try to attach with

```
MyModel.picture.attach(load_picture)
```

...but it fails. Probaly because the attachment is `nil`.

My question: How to download the image using a simple get request? Do I have to call something like `.attachment` on the response?

Comment: Hey Julian, have you checked other answers such as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61853410/how-to-attach-image-from-the-url-in-rails-active-storage

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer "@Christopher Oezbek" suggested:

Did the changes stated there and ir works! Perfect! Thanks!`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
YourModel.picture.attach(
  io: RestClient.get(url, :accept => 'image/jpg'),
  filename: 'IMAGE_NAME.jpg',
  content_type: 'image/jpg'
)
```

If you want more, go on https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#attaching-files-to-records. It will help you a lot.